# What's the best constructor

Tags: java, oop, constructor

Consider we have two classes `Line` and `Point` which class Line uses class `Point` as below:

```
public class Point {
   private int x;
   private int y;

   public Point(int x, int y) {
      this.x = x;
      this.y = y;
   }
}
```

and

```
public Class Line
{
   private Point start;
   private Point end;
   ...
}
```

I was wondering which of the constructors below are better for class Line due to OOP principles?

```
public Line(Point start, Point end)
{
   this.start = start;
   this.end = end;
}
```

or

```
public Line(int startX, int startY, int endX, int endY)
{
   start = new Point(startX, startY);
   end = new Point(endX, endY);
}
```

Comment: FYI, a separate site exists for offering code for review: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 10):

Definitely the first one. It is higher-level, the intent is clearer, it is more concise, and it is more maintainable with respect to changes to the Point class.

Comment: most of the time you will provide the second one as well.

Comment: @Larry - As soon as you provide the second one, even if it's just in addition to the first one, you've invalidated my last point, which is arguably the most important from an OOP standpoint. Consider what would happen if you wanted to extend this to three-dimensional Points.

Comment: From a puristic point of view that's true. However, if you end up typing  `new Line(new Point(x1,y1), new Point(x2,y2))` a hundred times, it makes much sense to provide the second one as a convenience method (alternatively using a factory method).

Comment: for the concern of freaking long parameter list, we can do param[]. I agree with Kiyura that the first one is more OO.

Answer (score 2):

I think it would be better to create instances of `Points` and then pass it to constructor, rather than leaving the constructor with one extra bit of work.

So, you should go with the first one. That way, constructor just needs to initialize the reference with the passed one, rather than to create itself.

Answer (score 0):

You could use both of them but if you are required a [composition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition) association only the second.